# How to implement a custom file system and is it necessary to add BIOS parameter block to my bootloader if I have a custom file system?

Tags: assembly, x86, filesystems, bootloader, osdev

---

I'm working on my own hobby-operating system and currently I'm trying to make a bootloader for my OS. I have read a few articles on [osdev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) and tried to implement those. Currently, my bootloader can print strings on the screen, load the stage-2 and load the GDT. I'll soon be working on other stuff like enabling A20 gate, entering protected/long mode, file system... **:)**

---

The bootloader I'm working on is going to have a custom file system. In this file system, each file will be of 512 bytes, if it exceeds 512 bytes then remaining part will be in next 512 bytes and both the sectors will be considered as a single file and so on for large files. There will be a *FDB* [File description block] of 32 bytes in beginning of each file...working on it's structure...**:)**

---

**!!!** But, I have to collect some more information before I start working on those. Here are a few questions,

- What is the real use of [Bios Parameter Block (BPB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block), I'm going to use a custom File System... Is it really necessary ?
- I'm not going to have a FAT Table, how to use BIOS disk read for my custom FS ?
- Also, most of the tutorials I found were for floppy, Nowadays almost no one uses floppy, my OS can only be emulated in bochs or qemu... Are there any tutorials for USB pen drive ?

  - It should be simple to understand, I found a project on github but it was too much confusing for me **:(**
- If I make a bootloader for USB will it's code remain same as that I coded for Floppy or will it be different for USB ?

---

Comment: How you decide to tackle implementing a file-system for your OS has to be your decision. ;)

Comment: I recommend you look into FAT, FAT32 and ISO-19011 support and start with those first, then NTFS, and then you would have a lot more experience to progress further with something completely custom yourself after having learnt about how the others work internally. For the record, Apple have some open-source code-base on an NTFS implementation for OS X support (while very old, still educational). https://opensource.apple.com/source/ntfs/

Comment: If you are using a floppy(or something emulating a floppy) that will do disk reads using CHS then having a BPB is useful because the formatting process will store drive geometry (heads, sectors per track, cylinders etc) in the BPB. You need such information (and it differs between floppy types) to do proper CHS to LBA translation. The BPB is also the format for a range of file systems- but if you are using your own it isn't required if you are on a hard disk or something emulating  a hard disk.

Comment: With that being said USBPen drives can be emulated as a floppy or a HDD.This is set in the BIOS. usually as USB HDD or USB FDD emulation. If you choose USB FDD (which is often the BIOS default) then your USB drive will almost certainly need a BPB even if it is a fake one with nothing in it. This is because most BIOSes these days will actually overwrite parts of the BPB with drive geometry info returned by the device BEFORE it starts executing the boot sector.

Comment: If you use USB HDD emulation you won't need a BPB with a custom file system, but fo rmany BIOSes you may need a partition table at the end of the boot sector with at least one partition marked active this is in addition to having 0xAA55 boot signature at the end. Some BIOSes may even require the first bytes on a disk's boot sector be a recognized instruction (like a JMP) or it may not be seen as a bootable device either.

Comment: Using HDD or USB HDD is advantageous over floppies because you can use the extended disk functions *Int 13h/AH=42h* for reads that support LBA (logical block addressing) rather than Cylinder/Head/Sector access (CHS can be a pain for anyone new to assembly or drive access)

Comment: So if you are going to embark on USB pen drives and you don't intend to be treated like a floppy I'd go into your BIOS configuration and in the options for USB booting ensure you have USB HDD (or USB Hard Drive emulation) enabled first.

Comment: You probably want to look at how non-Microsoft operating systems like Linux boot from USB drives.  Whatever they're doing should be pretty extensively tested across a wide range of systems.

Comment: Should also be pointed out that the BIOS interrupts for disk access only work in real mode or a VM8086 task. You can't use them from standard 32-bit protected mode. Your options would be to write a device driver that interfaces with the ATA (disk) controller directly; switch back into real mode do the BIOS access and switch back to protected mode; or create a VM8086 task (and minimal VM monitor)  that can do the BIOS call. Writing a device driver is the best option.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR: Why NTFS?  As a next step after simple FAT/FAT32, I'd suggest maybe something like ext2 or BSD ufs as simple but usable filesystems that can do sparse files, symlinks, hardlinks, owner/group, and large files.  They're well-documented and have up-to-date open source implementations.  (You're not going to want to risk corrupting your main computer's FSes, so compat with your Windows partition is probably not important in the near term).  But if you really want NTFS, there is up-to-date open-source https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/, with Linux FUSE support.